# Enconding UTF-8 issue when trying reading a json file

Tags: python, json, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I've got the error shown below when tryng to read a json file whose encode is UTF-8, can someone know how I can resolve this issue?

```
reviews = pd.read_csv('reviews.csv', nrows=1000)
businesses = pd.read_csv('businesses.csv', nrows=1000)
checkins = []
with open('checkins.json', encoding='utf-8')  as f:
    for row in f.readlines()[:1000]:
        checkins.append(json.loads(row))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4f54896faeca> in <module>
      3 checkins = []
      4 with open('checkins.json', encoding='utf-8')  as f:
----> 5     for row in f.readlines()[:1000]:
      6         checkins.append(json.loads(row))

~\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 37: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Looks like the file is corrupt. There's invalid UTF-8 in it. Look in position 37 of the file and see what's the problem

Comment: We can’t tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual contents of the data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors